# How to make Mat-Grid-List columns property dynamic?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want a Mat-Grid-List where I can dynamically change the amount of the "cols" property determined on the width of the box like follows:

```
<mat-grid-list [cols]="getAttachmentColumns()" rowHeight="100px" style="width: 100%;">
  <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let attachment of attachments; let i = index">
    ...
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

```
@ViewChild('attachments', {static: false}) attachments: ElementRef;
getAttachmentColumns(): number {
  if(this.attachments) {
    let n = Math.floor(this.attachments.nativeElement.clientWidth / 100);
    return (n > 0 ? n : 1);
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

With this code I allways get the following warning/error:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'cols: 1'. Current value: 'cols: 5'.
    at viewDebugError (core.js:25491)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:25468)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:25772)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:38548)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:38521)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:39482)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:39379)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (TicketDetailControlComponent.html:296)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:39364)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.js:38354)
```

Comment: works for me https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phjwd8

Comment: that is just the example from the angular docs and not answering my question

Comment: can you make a demo with your html would help. btw that's your code I did put in the stackblitz

Comment: here you can reproduce my error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-grid-list-dynamic-cols

Answer (score 0):

first import ChangeDetectorRef:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Then implement `ngAfterViewChecked` function like below.

```
constructor(private changeDetectorRef : ChangeDetectorRef){}

ngAfterViewChecked(){
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
}
```

That's work for me.